# HTML from database replace with bbcode

Tags: html, mysql, regex

I found some script on internet to from bbcode like [b] replace

```
function bbcodehtml($bbtext){
  $bbtags = array(
    '[b]' => '<strong>','[/b]' => '</strong>',
    '[i]' => '<em>','[/i]' => '</em>',
    '[u]' => '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">', '[/u]' => '</span>',
    '[code]' => '<blockquote>','[/code]' => '</blockquote>'
  );

  $bbtext = str_ireplace(array_keys($bbtags), array_values($bbtags), $bbtext);

  $bbextended = array(
    "/\[url](.*?)\[\/url]/i" => "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://$1\" title=\"$1\">$1</a>",
    "/\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/i" => "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\" title=\"$1\">$2</a>",
    "/\[img\]([^[]*)\[\/img\]/i" => "<img style=\"max-width:700px;\" src=\"$1\" alt=\" \" />",
    "/\[image\]([^[]*)\[\/image\]/i" => "<img style=\"max-width:700px;\" src=\"$1\" alt=\" \" />"
  );

  foreach($bbextended as $match=>$replacement){
    $bbtext = preg_replace($match, $replacement, $bbtext);
  }
  return $bbtext;
}
```

But now i have from when i want to display content in textarea i cant replace HTML for BBcodes..
I tried to change values for `preg_replace` and i got errors..

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add essential parts of your code (errors maybe). Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question. Place your errors here also.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...

1) Your code have many security problems. One for example. User can write text for XSS attack like this:

```
[img]" onmouseover="alert(document.cookie);[/img]
```

2) You must have TWO fields on DB, where first field contains source (unreplaced bb-codes) text, and second field contains replaced (readonly html) text. For this case you can run replace process (bb to html) only for create or edit text action.